Using WASM can I download the assemblies files before start the app in a html+js plain page used for login?
My intention is the following: I would like to have inside wwwroot a login page with very basic UI (just two texboxes and a button) with plain html + js + css. As soon as this page is loaded (document.onloadI guess) it starts asynchronously the downloading of the assemblies. When the user click the button to login it commit an ajax call to a API for authentication (json web token returns in response if credentials are valid). If the wasm files are already downloaded, the Blazor WASM appears. If the files are not yet downloaded, it wait until are downloaded and the Blazor WASM appears.
Is this feasible? I am trying but not success :-/

Does the authentication affect the Blazor Web Assembly assemblies download on the browser? If authentication failed, it would not download the assemblies?
